# How to compare single byte and multi bytes string?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two strings, one is input from client and other is data in table. Two strings seem to be the same, but has different hex value when I try `CAST_TO_RAW`.

```sql
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3539352F47502D0A41544258484E') INPUT,
       UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2('003500390035002F00470050002D000D000A00410054004200580048004E') DTA
  FROM DUAL;
/*input and data seem same*/
```

Consider that two string is the same. How I pass this case and compare them in query like this:

```sql
SELECT A.DATA,
       A.ORTHER_COL
  FROM MYTABLE A
 WHERE A.DATA = INPUT;
```

I tried `TO_SINGLE_BYTE` but it not work (because of its different `LENGTHB`):

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE TO_SINGLE_BYTE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3539352F47502D0A41544258484E')) =
       TO_SINGLE_BYTE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2('003500390035002F00470050002D000D000A00410054004200580048004E'));
/*return null*/
```

Comment: The two strings aren't the same, even allowing for the different characters sets; the second one has an extra `000D` in the middle.Are you expecting that to be ignored in the comparison?

Comment: Alex is right `WHERE A.DATA = INPUT` works fine if the strings would be the same, e.g. `SELECT * FROM dual WHERE UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3539') = UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2('00350039')`

Comment: yeah you right!

Comment: `Are you expecting that to be ignored in the comparison?`
@Alex Yes. I'm not sure that my data and my input have `char(13)` or not in runtime. Any workaround? I don't want to use `replace()` because I indexed `A.DATA`.

Comment: But if one has that carriage return and the other doesn't, why do you consider them the same, and which is 'right'? If you don't want to strip CR from the stored value then I guess you could replace a solo LF with CRLF in the input string instead. This sounds like a wider data issue though, or a problem with how the data is being supplied, maybe? e.g. could stored values also have solo LFs, or are they always CRLF; and where is the input coming from and should it already have CRLF anyway?.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I consider them the same because they "look" the same (based on end-user). Maybe I need replace LF with CRLF in my table because I already replaced input string this way.

Comment: @tungns304 - I've added a way you may be able to compare them directly without modification, but it may not be appropriate or performant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two string are not the same; the second one has an extra `000D` in the middle:

```
'3539352F47502D0A41544258484E'
             ^^^^
'003500390035002F00470050002D000D000A00410054004200580048004E'
                           ^^  ^^  ^^
```

If they were actually the same you could compare them with implicit conversion (adding the `0D` to the first string, but you may prefer to remove it from the second):

```
SELECT *
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3539352F47502D0D0A41544258484E') =
       UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2('003500390035002F00470050002D000D000A00410054004200580048004E');

D
-
X
```

Or explicitly cat to `nvarchar2`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE cast(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3539352F47502D0D0A41544258484E') as nvarchar2(2000)) =
       UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2('003500390035002F00470050002D000D000A00410054004200580048004E');

D
-
X
```

or the other way:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3539352F47502D0D0A41544258484E') =
       cast(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2('003500390035002F00470050002D000D000A00410054004200580048004E') as varchar2(4000));

D
-
X
```

It's possible you could see some oddities from the casting I suppose, depending on the raw data and the two DB character sets.

---

From Oracle 12c you could potentially use [a UCA linguistic collation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-6ADFC7B7-5857-4962-BED9-E1975CEDD0C8) that [ignores](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-92E6F5BE-036E-4454-88F5-D810EF7DC93C) the difference between LF and CRLF, e.g.:

```
alter session set nls_sort = 'UCA0700_ORADUCET_S1';
alter session set nls_comp = 'LINGUISTIC';

SELECT *
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3539352F47502D0A41544258484E') =
       UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2('003500390035002F00470050002D000D000A00410054004200580048004E');

D
-
X
```

You'd need to see what effect it had on performance though, and whether the other ignorable characters would cause false matches. If you *only* want to ignore discrepancies between LF/CRLF then you're probably stuck with sanitising the data to be consistent.

Comment: I feel ashamed. I think I checked this case before posting a question. Good to know that problems come from another part of the process.

Comment: Easy to miss; I had to `dump()` both generated values before I noticed they were different lengths *8-)